# adding the amount of letters there are in a string in python

Tags: python

My code adds the letters together. But I only need to count the number of letters.

For example, for the input string "a12a", the output will be `2` because there are 2 letters.

```py
def countingletters(st):
    empty = []
    for i in st:
        if i.isalpha():
            empty += str(i)

    return empty
```

Comment: Well, why are you using a list to count things?

Comment: `my_string = 'a12a';
sum(c.isalpha() for c in my_string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Method 1:** Using a list (as you did)

```
def countingletters(st):
    empty = []
    for i in st:
        if i.isalpha():
             empty += str(i)

    return len(empty)

# test
print(countingletters("a12a")) # display 2
```

> **Method 2:** Use a counter

```
def countingletters(st):
    cpt = 0 # the counter
    for i in st:
        if i.isalpha():
            cpt += 1
    return cpt


# test
print(countingletters("a12a")) # display 2
```

> **Method 3:** Using a list comprehensions

```
def countingletters(st):
    return len([i for i in st if i.isalpha()])

# test
print(countingletters("a12a")) # display 2
```

Comment: Method 4: Use a generator expression. `sum(c.isalpha() for c in st)`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
def countingletters(st):
    empty = []
    for i in st:
        if i.isalpha():
             empty+= str(i)

    count_letters = len(empty)
    print(count_letters)

    return empty
```

Just count the len of the array with the letters. I don't know if you want to print the result but that's the answer.

Comment: Well, just an example, the important part is de variable count_letters = len(empty)

Comment: Not sure how this got upvoted considering it doesn't even work. `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Answer (score 1):

> it adds the letters together

Not quite... It appends letters to a list, separately, not combines all letters together

You could simply `return len(empty)`, however maintaining a list instead of just an integer is not the optimal solution

Comment: If you have to count _unique_ letters, that's a different solution

Comment: The OP's example makes it clear that `aa` counts as two, not one.